# print after finish load html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an HTML table in a $ .each, once this element over the command to print in a new window that immediately shows the print but shows the print screen empty if cancel the printing screen has the elemente created and I try to print now show me the items on the screen printing.

How can I make sure it's loaded with the items over to send print ???

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
    Popup(elem);
}

function Popup(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Report');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Report</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link href="'+path+'Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    //alert(data);
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    //setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);

    /*function myFunction() {
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }*/

    /*$(mywindow).load(function () {
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    });*/

    //mywindow.print();
    //mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

i am try with setTimeout but i dont think that its the better solution
any idea what can i do??

Comment: Put the JS just before the closing `body` tag? Maybe listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Answer (score 1):

You could use windows.onload to load your function

```
window.onload=function()
{
 PrintElem();
}
```